# Touch Screen not working on MS Surface Pro 4 after install (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Tags: touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu on a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 and the touch screen doesn't work. All other answers for this question are of older versions of Ubuntu. Everything else works it's just the touchscreen.

Comment: Try the Linux Surface kernel https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface , https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

Comment: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Pro-4#how-to-get-touch-working-properly-on-surface-pro-4-the-definitive-guide

Comment: By the way, does the camera work?

Comment: Thank you @ArchismanPanigrahi the surface kernel that you recommended fixed my problem. I didn't get to check if the camera works because I don't an app installed to use the camera but i'll get back to you about that.

Comment: To test camera, you can use Cheese Webcam Booth. `sudo apt install cheese`. I am curious to know if everything in Surface Pro 4 work in Ubuntu, that's why.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use the linux-surface kernel, as [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458314/touch-screen-not-working-on-ms-surface-pro-4-after-install-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts?noredirect=1#comment2551010_1458314) by @Archisman Panigrahi.

The instructions below are copied from the original article in the linux-surface kernel wiki: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

> First you need to import the keys we use to sign packages.
>
> ```bash
> wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc \
>         | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-surface.gpg
> ```
>
> After this you can add the repository configuration and update APT.
>
> ```bash
> echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" \
>         | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> If you encounter any issues reading "Error 401 Unauthorized" during
> the update or the installation below, please have a look at [this](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Known-Issues-and-FAQ#apt-update-fails-on-ubuntudebian-based-distributions-with-error-401-unauthorized).
>
> Now you can install the linux-surface kernel and its dependencies.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface libwacom-surface iptsd
> ```
>
> **Important:** Support for iptsd only goes back to the latest LTS release
> at the time of writing (Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04). If you are using
> an older release, and the above command fails, then please remove
> `iptsd` from it. You will still be able to use basic singletouch through
> the kernel driver, but multitouch and the stylus will not work.
>
> After that you can install our secureboot key. This will import the
> key that the linux-surface kernel is signed with into your bootloader,
> so that the kernel is bootable without disabling secureboot.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-surface-secureboot-mok
> ```
>
> This package will print instructions to the terminal. In case you
> missed those: It will ask you to reboot. Then, upon reboot, a blue
> menu should pop up, asking you whether you want to enroll the key.
> Confirm with `ok`/`yes` and when asked for a password enter `surface`. In
> case you missed the menu or accidentally chose the wrong options, you
> can uninstall (fully) and then reinstall the package and reboot to
> trigger the menu again.
>
> Note that this will only work if your Debian derivative supports
> secure boot out-of-the-box. If if not, please consult the wiki of your
> distribution and set up secure boot for distro/stock kernels first.
> You also want to skip installing the package for now and only install
> it after you have set this up.
>
> The linux-surface kernel will be installed alongside the default
> kernel provided by the distribution. This way you have a backup kernel
> you can use if something goes wrong. The bootloader will pick up the
> kernel by default, but you should update its configuration to make
> sure it was recognized.
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Finally, reboot your system and you should boot into the linux-surface
> kernel. Please make sure you are actually using the right kernel by
> checking if the output of `uname -a` contains the string `surface`. If it
> doesn't contain that string, you are still using the default kernel
> and need to configure your bootloader.

Comment: Yeah the Camera isn't working. I get a lot of errors when I try to use it. @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Is there a bash installer or a package built for this yet?